# PostgreSQL on my Windows 11 local machine keeps running the installer again and again at a random schedule

Tags: postgresql, windows, reinstall

I have installed PostgreSQL 15 the most current version on my Windows 11 machine locally.  It runs fine.  However, a very strange thing is happening. All of a sudden, after a day or two, the installer runs completely over again.  I uninstalled postgreSQL using Windows Add/Remove.  Deleted any leftover files that were not removed, and reinstalled again.  It installed fine and works fine but just now, it reran the installer and completely reinstalled PostgreSQL again.  Mind you, I have removed the install executables, i.e., deleted them from my machine thinking somehow some process gets hold of it and runs it again.  But that is not the issue since I physically removed the executable installer.

I don't know how to go about figuring it out.  Please advise.

Thanks.

Bharat